# Loop through each website (IIS) via powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis

So I need to loop through all of my websites (some 30 of them) on IIS 7.5 and then do an AppCmd command against each (in this case, changing the anonymous user/password)...

Is this how you would do this?

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
foreach ($Site in $Websites) {
  DoSomething
   }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

So this indeed works:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
foreach ($Site in $Websites) {
  DOSOMETHING
 }
```

For example,

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
foreach ($Site in $Websites) {
  Write-Host $Site.name
 }
```

Comment: There is a bug that some might run into--I ran into when doing this on my system.  See http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/5172-error-using-get-website-in-predeploy-because-of-filenotfoundexception.